# Only click next page button after the first page has been scraped and then scrape next page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

How would I make selenium wait for scrapy to scrape the information needed from the first page, and only then click the next page button and then scrape the next page. Ultimately I am trying to repeat this process until the last page is reached which is page 301.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from typing_extensions import Self
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from time import sleep
from turtle import delay
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which 

#login info
username = "xxx"
password = "xxx"

class HtSpiderSelenium(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ht_selenium1'
    allowed_domains = ['https://app.xxx.bootstart.tech']
    start_urls = ['https://app.xxx.bootstart.tech']
    
    def __init__(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        #chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver")

        #get login page
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
        driver.get("https://auth.bootstart.tech/auth/realms/xxxPlatform/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=xxx-platform&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.xxx.bootstart.tech%2F%3Fredirect_fragment%3D%252Fstartup&state=8780862b-1eaf-4b6e-92e5-fd9ab464c57f&nonce=79d66ef5-f0bb-4e75-8db2-6402114b9aa8&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code")

        #login
        driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(username)
        driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password)
        driver.find_element_by_name("login").click()
        sleep(15)

        #next page button
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[14]/a").click()
        sleep(10)


        self.html = driver.page_source
        driver.close()

    #scrape needed info
    def parse(self, response):
        resp = Selector(text=self.html)
        for startup in resp.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'col-sm-12')]"):
            yield {
                'startup name': startup.xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'no-outline ng-binding')]/text()").get(),
                'startup descript': ''.join(startup.xpath('//div//p//div//text()').getall()),
                'startup location': startup.xpath(".//h4//small[@class='ng-binding']//text()").get(),
                'startup industry': startup.xpath(".//h4//span[@class='ng-binding']/text()").get(),
            }
```

Comment: from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException \n
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait    \n                   
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)  \n #in try except bl;ock, you can wait to check if any specific element that is needed to be scrpped is loaded and then once its there you can add sleep may be 1-2 sec depending on content of that page and then go to next page . if this can be of any help

Comment: @aryansingh maybe I misunderstood, but the elements that need to be scraped are the same on every page, what type of element should the webdriver wait for?

Comment: maybe last element in the page by id or XPath or it can be any element that can confirm that page has loaded completely as after that getting the content can be done fast and once can move to next page, I used this method for scrapping pdf content from a page , it worked fine

Comment: @BerciVagyok After the `__init__` finishes scrapy will enter the `parse` method. Either make a for loop for the pagination and add the sources to a list `self.html_list.append(driver.page_source)` and loop through it in parse, or just use a selector to parse it in the for loop. BTW don't you prefer to use a middleware for selenium for this spider?

Comment: @SuperUser I tried using the scrapy_selenium middleware, but there I am stuck on how to login to the website since once I am logged in the URL changes and when using it the course I did used url = xxxx and does not cover login first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do something like this:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# from typing_extensions import Self
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
# from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from time import sleep
from turtle import delay
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which

#login info
username = "xxx"
password = "xxx"


class HtSpiderSelenium(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ht_selenium1'
    allowed_domains = ['app.xxx.bootstart.tech']


    def __init__(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        #chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver")

        #get login page
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
        self.driver.get("https://auth.bootstart.tech/auth/realms/xxxPlatform/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=xxx-platform&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.xxx.bootstart.tech%2F%3Fredirect_fragment%3D%252Fstartup&state=8780862b-1eaf-4b6e-92e5-fd9ab464c57f&nonce=79d66ef5-f0bb-4e75-8db2-6402114b9aa8&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code")

        #login
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("login").click()

        self.start_urls = [self.driver.current_url]

    #scrape needed info
    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        while True:
            resp = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
            for startup in resp.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'col-sm-12')]"):
                yield {
                    'startup name': startup.xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'no-outline ng-binding')]/text()").get(),
                    'startup description': ''.join(startup.xpath('//div//p//div//text()').getall()),
                    'startup location': startup.xpath(".//h4//small[@class='ng-binding']//text()").get(),
                    'startup industry': startup.xpath(".//h4//span[@class='ng-binding']/text()").get(),
                }

            #next page button
            next_page = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[14]/a")
            try:
                next_page.click()
            except:
                break
        self.driver.close()
```

Comment: thank you so much, it has finally worked all I had to change was to add a few sleep :D Helped me so much!!!